# ¿Qué módulo puedo utilizar para detectar y conectarme a las redes Wi-Fi alrededor?

Tags: python, python-2.7

La idea general de lo que quiero hacer es conectarme a una red Wi-Fi pero desde Python y me preguntaba cuál es el módulo más recomendado para lograr esta funcionalidad, preferiblemente una solución para OSX, los módulos que encontré no tienen una documentación del todo clara, busco algo fácil de usar.

Comment: Estaba planteándome una respuesta, pero la pregunta es muy amplia, por favor concreta. Buscando de forma rápida aparece [wifi](https://github.com/rockymeza/wifi), o si no puedes usar librerías de automatización de comandos como [Invoke](http://www.pyinvoke.org/)

Comment: para que sistema operativo?

Comment: Estoy utilizando OS X El Capitan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solo mencionas que tu objetivo es conectarte. Haciendo una pequeña búsqueda encontré [`wireless`](https://github.com/joshvillbrandt/wireless) que parece ser más sencillo de usar que [`wifi`](https://github.com/rockymeza/wifi) (por lo menos para el tema de la conexión). Su última actualización es de hace algunos meses.

Usando Linux:

```
$ sudo pip install wireless
```

En la documentación no mencionan una forma de listar las redes Wi-Fi disponibles. Pero, por ejemplo, yo tengo una red llamada `DEPART_301`:

```
>>> from wireless import Wireless
>>> wireless = Wireless()
>>> wireless.interface()
'wlan0'
>>> wireless.connect(ssid='DEPART_301', password='******')
True
```

Estuve conectado a otra red del edificio en el que vivo y pude hacer el cambio de la red `DEPART_401` a la red `DEPART_301` perfectamente.

Si quieres listar las redes disponibles tal vez puedas mezclarlo con el módulo `wifi`:

```
$ sudo pip install wifi
```

Para listar redes disponibles:

```
>>> from wifi import Cell
>>> for cell in Cell.all('wlan0'): print cell.ssid
DEPART_301
DEPART_401
DPTO402
MEGHAN202020
NAT
```

Comment: Muchas gracias César, es lo que estaba buscando 1) obtener una lista de redes disponibles y 2) como conectarme a una de ellas. Sabes alguna forma de hacerlo en OSX ? Es común que existan soluciones fáciles solo para linux como al parecer es esta ?

Comment: @AndrésMuñoz wireless es multiplataforma. Por cierto, parece que puedes listar las redes disponibles con `interfaces()` https://github.com/joshvillbrandt/wireless#api